# Looking for a SQL to Relational Algebra parser/api in java

Tags: java, sql, api, parsing, relational-algebra

A part of my project includes converting the given SQL statements in Relational Algebra `(SQL -> RA and then RA -> SQL)` apply some rules and convert it back to SQL.

Can some one recommend me a good api for that? so far i have found some GUIs that do the conversions and visualisations but if there is an api or parser available please recomend me?

Comment: I do not think you can convert  100% of SQL to relational calculus or algebra because relational calculus is a subset of SQL but you can parse  SQL to AST transform AST, I use patched version of jsqlparser https://github.com/jbaliuka/sql-analytic .